# Evaluating average spin components in a 1D quantum spin chain

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-spin

Given a Hamiltonian with Pauli matrices:

$\hat H = - J \sum_i \sigma^x_i \sigma^x_{i+1} - h \sum_i \sigma^z_i$
, $h$ being an external field,

I want to evaluate $\langle \sigma_i^z \rangle$ and  $\langle \sigma_i^x \rangle$ in the ground state for two cases: $h\rightarrow \infty $, $h=0$.

My notes define the ground state as $|gs\rangle = \otimes_i (1\ 0)^T$.

I get the physical argument in all 4 cases, but I fail to see how $h$ enters in any of the averages.

So, how to show mathematically with kets and matrices, that e.g. for $h = 0 $:

$\langle \sigma_i^x \rangle_{gs} = \pm 1$ ?

Any pointers to relevant resources appreciated as well.

Comment: For $h=0$, then the Hamiltonian is purely $\sigma_i^x \sigma_{i+1}^x$, so the ground state is purely dictated by this term. For $h \to \infty$, the Hamiltonian is purely $\sigma_i^z$, so the ground state is purely dictated by this term (including perhaps the sign of $h$). Does this help with your question or am I missing the point?

Comment: @HarryLevine I do not see how the averages explicitly depend on h. I would like to find this dependence, so that I can take my h limits then.

Comment: I see what you mean. Near the phase transition point ($h \sim 1$), the ground state will be highly nontrivial, so I am not sure how to calculate these values there. However, you could begin with the known ground state at $h=0$, and then perturbatively add the $\sigma^z$ term to find out how these expectation values depend on small $h$. This may not be the approach you are hoping for though...